# Firestore backup without paying high prices

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Import and Export helps make it easier to run backups in Firestore as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import)

Backing up a Firestore database means a read for every document. That seems incredibly expensive.
Similarly, it would seemingly cost highly when trying to restore a backup.

Is there any way to run these backups without having to incur such high costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a backup of your documents requires reading those documents. There is currently no way to create a backup without (charged) reading of each document.